# Why is fwrite so much slower in binary mode?

Tags: c++, qt, optimization, io

I have a buffer of roughly 2GB of raw binary data stored in a [QByteArray](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html) that I'm trying to write the fastest way possible. Because [QFile](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfile.html) was noticeably slower, I went back to dabbling in C/C++-style writing, which I haven't done for a couple years so I'm very rusty.

Sample code:

```
QFile in("D:/input.las");
in.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QByteArray junk = in.readAll();
in.close();

QFile test1("D:/samplelas/bigset2/out/_test1.las");
test1.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Truncate);
if(test1.isOpen())
{
    QElapsedTimer t;
    t.start();
    test1.write(junk);
    test1.close();
    qDebug("Round\t%'i\tTest QFile\ttook\t%'i", i+1, t.elapsed());
}

FILE* test2 = fopen("D:/_test2.las", "wb");
if(test2)
{
    QElapsedTimer t;
    t.start();
    fwrite(junk.constData(), sizeof(char), junk.size(), test2);
    fclose(test2);
    qDebug("Round\t%'i\tTest wb\ttook\t%'i", i+1, t.elapsed());
}

FILE* test3 = fopen("D:/_test3.las", "w");
if(test3)
{
    QElapsedTimer t;
    t.start();
    fwrite(junk.constData(), sizeof(char), junk.size(), test3);
    fclose(test3);
    qDebug("Round\t%'i\tTest w\ttook\t%'i", i+1, t.elapsed());
}
```

I noticed that using `"w"` instead of `"wb"` corrupted the output because "newline" characters were interpreted on my Windows machine (rookie mistake). Still, the results were promising, so I tried again with "wb" instead.

I was extremely startled to find that binary mode was slower by a factor of 5-10x and I can't figure out why. If anything, the non-binary mode write should be *faster* because it's not interpreted, just raw data.

What am I missing?

**Edit1:** Testing in release mode using Qt 4.8.6 on MSVC2010, Windows 7x64 Pro.

**Edit2:** Added QFile test case and clarified explanation of the issue.

Comment: What happens if you flip the code around and do the non binary write first?  Is it still faster?

Comment: Have you tried it in both release and debug modes?

Comment: @George This is in release mode. I edited the question to add environment info.

Comment: @NathanOliver Hold on... I just realized I had my labels backward so you were correct - flipping the code resulted in the opposite result. Why is that?

Comment: @Phlucious Sounds like disk caching.  On the first file it misses so it a long write but the second file hits so it is much shorter.

Comment: @NathanOliver I redid the benchmarks by running each test 10 times independently (10x with "wb" and 10x with "w", with a full restart in between), and the binary is still significantly slower – 27 seconds vs 5 seconds.

Comment: There's no way to answer anything without you posting a complete, self-contained test case - ideally one that's not broken to start with. Your primary problem is, most likely, that you write to disk, and that skews the results. Write to NUL instead. Also, `QFile` should not be any slower than raw writes.

Comment: @KubaOber Writing the same block of data using QFile::write is halfway in between the binary and non-binary fwrite methods - around 15 seconds. I don't know how I can boil down the provided test cases more than I have... simply comment out the two tests that aren't being performed that time. Your suggestion to write to NUL doesn't make sense... writing to disk is exactly what I'm testing.

Comment: @Phlucious But you're not testing writing to disk because, among other things, your test terminates without waiting for the data to be written to disk! What you're measuring is how long you have to wait before you can write to disk. (That is, how long before enough of a previous write is flushed that there's room to cache the next one.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Interesting... I'm seeing exactly the amount of data I expect to see in the output files. Doesn't [fclose()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fclose/) force the device to flush before closing it and it goes out of scope?

Comment: @Phlucious No, it doesn't. Why would it? That would make a programs that modify lots of little files run absurdly slow.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Because "All internal buffers associated with the stream are disassociated from it and flushed: the content of any unwritten output buffer is written and the content of any unread input buffer is discarded." from cplusplus.com

Comment: @Phlucious You are drastically misunderstanding that! When it says "is written", they mean to the OS and filesystem (and thus are visible to other programs talking to the same OS and filesystem), not to the disk!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130652/discussion-between-phlucious-and-david-schwartz).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm totally wrong, but the reason that I see (based in your code) for that performance difference is the confusion with the `fwrite` function parameters in these lines:

```
fwrite(junk.constData(), sizeof(char), junk.size(), <file>);
```

Let's review the definition of that function:

```
size_t fwrite (const void* buff, size_t size, size_t count, FILE* stream);
```

Where:

- `size` Is the block size to write.
- `count` Is the quantity of blocks to write
- `stream` Is, in this case, the file to write into.
- The function returns a `size_t` with the quantity of blocks succesfully written.

Now, the meaning of those parameters totally depend on the `fwrite` implementation code. In some cases (like FreeBSD's libc) the implementation simply does something like `total = size*count` and make one system call to write the entire buffer. But in another implementations (like Microsoft's), it's a different story:

**Meaning in Text mode**

The fwrite will:

- Copy blocks of `size` bytes each into an internal memory buffer of `BUFSIZ` bytes of size (normally 512, if not changed by user)
- Convert all newline chars
- Make one system call to write that internal `BUFSIZ` buffer, when it is full.
- If it cannot complete that system call, returns with the number of blocks already written till now.
- Do all over again until `count` blocks will be written or an error happen.

In your code: The fwrite will make aprox. (junk.size()/512) of system calls.

**Meaning in Binary mode**

The fwrite will:

- Make a loop from 1 to `count` iterations:
- In each iteration, it will make one system call to write one blocks of `size` bytes into that file.
- If it cannot complete that system call, returns with the number of blocks already written till now.
- Do all over again until `count` blocks will be written or an error happen.

In your code: The fwrite will make ~512x more system calls than in the text mode (why it is only 10x slower? that's another question).

Comment: Interesting... If that was true, wouldn't I see a noticeable performance gain by swapping `size` and `count`? That doesn't appear to be the case.